# How to display characer '¿' on Label with React-Native?

Tags: android, react-native, character-encoding

For some reason when I try to display this character in a React-Native Android App, it display other character.

This is how it looks like.
[image]

This is my code.

```
<Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Cochin'}}>¿Existio presencia y/o parte policial?</Text>
```

Is this a problem of the Font, or character encoding, how to solve?

Comment: This "other character" is shown when the desired character does not exist in the font you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simplest way, you can use unicode character to display inverse question mark

```
<Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Cochin'}}>"\u00BF Existio presencia y/o parte policial?"</Text>
```